# If $f$ normal operator and $f(W)\subset W$ then $f^*(W)\subset W$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a Hermitian finite-dimensional space and $f:V\to V$ be a normal operator. If $W$ is invariant subspace of $V$ under $f$ show that $W$ is also invariant under $f^*$.

**My attempt:** Since the space is Hermitian and $f$ is normal then there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, say $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ with $f(e_i)=\lambda_i e_i$

My goal to show that $f^*(W)\subseteq W$. Let $x\in W$ then $x=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_i e_i$ and $f^*(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_i f^*(e_i)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_i \overline{\lambda_i}e_i$ because $f^*(e_i)=\overline{\lambda_i}e_i$. Since $f(W)\subseteq W$ then it follows that $f(x)=\sum \limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\lambda_i e_i\in W$.  We see that those sums differ just by conjugation.

Probably I have to use smth else in order to complete but I do not know.

Could anyone show how to finish the proof, please?

Comment: The space is Hermitian , What about proper values ? I think they are real there is no differ in your two both sum

Comment: Eigenvalues of normal operator can be complex number with nonzero imaginary part.

Comment: It is not given that the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: @ZFR I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Since $V$ is Hermitian finite-dimensional vector space and $f:V\to V$ is normal operator then there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ with $f(e_i)=\lambda_i e_i$. Then $f^*(e_i)=\overline{\lambda_i}e_i$. Let $\{\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n\}$ - eigenvalues of $f$  then one can find polynomial $p(t)$ such that $p(\lambda_i)=\overline{\lambda_i}$ and it follows that $p(f)=f^*$. Suppose $p(t)=a_nt^n+\dots+a_1t+a_0$ and since $f(W)\subseteq W$ then $f^k(W)\subseteq W$ and it immediately follows that $f^*(W)=p(f)(W)\subseteq W.$

The last inclusion shows that $W$ is $f^*$-invariant.